# Pulling information from Itunes Top songs rss feed(xml) with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to pull data from itunes top 100 rss feed. I can't seem to pull data from tags like `<im:name>`

Code:

```
var loadFunction = function() {
        $.get( "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=10/xml", function(data) {
            //$("#student").html("");
            var studentArray = $(data).find("entry");

            studentArray.each(function() {
                var sname = $(this).find("title").text();
                var sid = $(this).find("im:name").text();
                var fees = $(this).find("fees").text();
                var units = $(this).find("fees").attr("units");
                $("#student").append(
                    "<h3>" + sname + "</h3>ID:" + 
                    sid + "<br>Fees to be paid:" + 
                    fees + " " + units + "<br>");
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(loadFunction);
```

The title tag works, but the i:name tag doesn't. I have no idea why.

The xml/ link for the data is in the load function under the $.get(....).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's namespaced...change it to this:

```
var sid = $(this).find("im\\:name").text();
```

Comment: What do you mean by its namespaced?

Comment: That's what the 'im' part is. It's a way of avoiding naming conflicts in XML. For instance, there could be another node named hm:name. The catch is that you have to escape the colon. That's the issue here. if you're curios about namespacing, [here's more info](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

Comment: It ends up giving me the data from the name tag which is "Blank spaces" is also gives me the album name which is "1989" is there a way to break these two up into two different variables?

Comment: not sure, but Blank space is actually the name of the first song--<title>Blank Space - Taylor Swift</title><im:name>Blank Space</im:name>

Comment: Found a way, thank for everything. I might ask a few more questions!

Comment: There are three image tags they all have the same tag name, but different heights. I want to get the link of one of them and post it as a picture. How do I go about this?